# If an extinction capable asteroid was approaching Earth, would we be capable of preventing the collision?

Tags: asteroid, asteroid-redirect-mission

Assuming we just spotted an asteroid, of a similar size to the one that killed the dinosaurs, that is approaching earth and will hit it in an equally fatal way.

Presuming we detected this asteroid as early as possible:

Would Humanity be able to ensure the prevention of this event within the given time?

And if so what would be reasonable steps to prevent this?

Comment: ok, I'll do it. but is this anyway best place for both questions or should I maybe split them on different SE pages? + should this be closed untill then or should i just delete the post untill its improved?

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto: Well the marked dup is what I was looking for, but isn't satisfying to me. I would like to know those named options in more detail and also would love to ask for what the soon launched telescope would be able to detect as maximum range and how close an object had to be to be detected for almost 100%. So question remains: Is this SE page the best place for both of the questions I'm planing to ask?

Comment: @Zaibis Yes, I think this is a good place to ask. For the first, I would suggest asking for one proposed method at a time. For the second, I would have a more specific value than "almost 100%" in mind--do you mean 99.9 or 99.99 or 99.999...etc.

Comment: Thanks for your hints. I'll think about it and phrase my question(s) after at least reading the related wikipedia articles. thanks so far.